# Strong convergence with comparable speed implies uniform convergence

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, metric-spaces

Let $X$ be a Banach space and $(T_n)_n$ a sequence of bounded operators on $X$. Suppose there is a sequence $(q_n)_n$ in $\mathbb R$ converging to $0$ such that for each $x \in X$ there is $M_x > 0$ such that $\lVert T_n x \rVert \leq M_x q_n$. I want to show that this implies $T_n \to 0$ uniformly.

I thought Baire's theorem should do the trick:

Let $\varepsilon > 0$ and consider the sets $A_k := \{x \in X : \forall n \geq k: \lVert T_n x \rVert \leq \varepsilon \}$. Then it is clear that the $A_k$'s are closed, $A_k \subseteq A_{k + 1}$ and $X = \bigcup_{k \in \mathbb N} A_k$. Hence, there is $K \in \mathbb N$ such that $A_K$ has non-empty interior. In particular, there is $x_0 \in X$ and $r_0 > 0$ such that $B(x_0, r_0) \subseteq A_K$. Now for $x \in B[0, 1]$ and $0 < r < r_0$ I estimate as follows:

$$\lVert T_n x \rVert \leq \frac 1 r (\lVert T_n x_0 \rVert + \lVert T_n (rx + x_0) \rVert) \leq \frac{2\varepsilon}{r} \overset{r \to r_0} \longrightarrow \frac{2\varepsilon}{r_0}$$

and hence $\lVert T_n \rVert \leq \frac{2\varepsilon}{r_0}$ for all $n \geq K$. But $r_0$ depends on $\varepsilon$ so this does not give me the desired conclusion. I also tried other set families $(A_k)_k$ but I seem to struggle to find the right one. I think my main problem is that my $A_k$'s do not make use of the fact that $\lVert T_n x \rVert \leq M_x \varepsilon$ for big $n$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You did not make use of the sequence $(q_n)$. Apply your argument to $S_n=\frac {T_n} {\sqrt {q_n}}$ with $\epsilon =1$. You will get $\|S_nx\| \leq \frac  2 {r_0}$ or $\|T_n x\| \leq \sqrt {q_n} \frac  2 {r_0} $ for $\|x\|\leq 1$.

Comment: I do not see how to show that for $n$ big enough $\lVert S_n x \rVert \leq 1$ for each $x \in X$.

Comment: Just replace $T_n$ by $S_n$ in your argument and see what you get.

Comment: I did. But I cannot show that $\lVert q_n^{-1/2} T_n x \rVert \leq 1$ for all $n$ big enough. So I cannot conclude that $X = \bigcup_k A_k$ and hence I cannot use my argument. Am I missing something? Please clearify!

Comment: @Yaddle $M_x \sqrt {q_n} \to 0$, right?